# How do I simulate a poker hand dealing in R?

Tags: r

I play an online poker game, and I am concerned that the initial hands dealt to the player are not random after what seems to me after many observations too many non-random distributions. I'm trying to take 200-1000 hands dealt and compare it to a simulation to compare the distributions and see if it is indeed random. If it is, I would expect a uniform distribution. Anyways, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to store an array of 1,000 deals with two cards to each hand. Below is the code I have but every output prints out the same "2C and KC", 1000 times. Replace needs to equal false, since identical cards can't be dealt. I'd appreciate any help with solving this simulation, as well as any advice anyone may have as to going about this experiment. Thanks in advance!

```
cardDeck <- c("AH", "1H", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "10H", "JH", "QH", "KH",
              "AS", "1S", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "JS", "QS", "KS",
              "AC", "1C", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "10C", "JC", "QC", "KC",
              "AD", "1D", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "10D", "JD", "QD", "KD")

deal <- function(cardDeck) {
  cardOne <- sample(cardDeck, 1, replace = FALSE)
  cardTwo <- sample(cardDeck, 1, replace = FALSE)
  handDealt <- paste(cardOne, cardTwo, sep = " and ")
}

cardsDealt <- rep(deal(cardDeck), 1000)
```

Comment: Try instead `paste(sample(cardDeck, 2, replace=FALSE), collapse = " and ")`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien that won't fix the problem.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Well, it certainly fixes "a" problem. If you resample form the same set twice, you may get two identical cards. Replace is only relevant for a single call to the function.

Comment: Also, you can make your deck with `cardDeck <- do.call(paste0, expand.grid(c("A", 1:10, c("J","Q","K")), c("H","S","C","D")))`

Comment: You're only going to get random distributions to the limit of your underlying PRNG.  If you don't know what that means,you're not really at a level to start questioning the randomness (or, to be exact, the fairness) of the hands dealt in the online game.  I would also point out that what you want is `sample(1:52,2,replace=FALSE)` , since the actual cards' names are irrelevant to testing a distribution.

Comment: There is the `random` CRAN package for more "true" randomness.

Comment: @MrFlick there is more than one (P)RNG built into R: `?Random`

Comment: FWIW, in the poker domain, 1000 hands is way to small of a sample to draw any statically significant inferences. Also, if you're just looking at starting hands dealt, you're probably much better off calculating the probabilities analytically.

Comment: I'm not as concerned with the sample size right now as I am setting the simulation and actual observations up correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `replicate`, which will evaluate `deal(cardDeck)` 1000 times, instead of `rep` which will evaluate it once and then broadcast the result 1000 times. This is because the argument to `replicate` is an `expression`, whereas `rep` uses R's typical pass-by-value behavior, in that the arguments are evaluated *before* the function is called.

Comment: cardsDealt <- replicate(deal(cardDeck), 1000)

returns the following error, however:

    Error in integer(n) : invalid 'length' argument

Comment: @JasonT.Eyerly the syntax is different. Take a look at `args(replicate)` or just `?replicate`...

Answer (score 5):

Here are some improvements:

Generate deck compactly:

```
cardDeck <- c(outer(c("A",1:10,"J","Q","K"),
                    c("H","S","C","D"),
                    ## could use
                    ## "\u2661","\u2662","\u2667", "\u2664"
                  paste0))
```

As pointed out in comments, you need to choose all the cards in a hand in a single `sample()` call in order to get proper sampling without replacement (if you want to sample multiple hands from a single deal you need to modify this to sample all the cards from all the hands in a single `sample()` statement)

```
deal <- function(n=2,collapse=" and ") {
  paste(sample(cardDeck, n, replace=FALSE),
         collapse=collapse)
}
```

Use `replicate()` as suggested in comments and @ssdecontrol's answer:

```
set.seed(101)
replicate(5,deal())
## [1] "6S and 2H" "JC and 8C" "KH and 2S" "4C and 4S" "6C and 2C"
```